# Swift Parse : How to Push Notification To a Specific Device/objectId

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

i'm trying to push notification to a specific user in my User Table, but my function didn't work and i don't understand why.

```
func testPush(){
    let message = "Alert !!"
    let id = "88yhi9j0"

    var data = [ "title": "Some Title",
        "alert": message]

    var userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    userQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: id)
    var query: PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()
    query.whereKey("currentUser", equalTo: userQuery)

    var push: PFPush = PFPush()
    push.setQuery(query)
    push.setData(data)
    push.sendPushInBackground()
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: This is very helpful, but I am trying to figure out how to access a specific id the way you set id to "88yhi9j0". Where can I find a list of users for my app by id?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is in the line:

```
query.whereKey("currentUser", equalTo: userQuery)
```

It should be:

```
query.whereKey("currentUser", matchesQuery: userQuery)
```

I hope this solves the issue.

Comment: I don't recieve notification on the other device, i'm looking why now