# Unable to send push notification to a single user with Parse - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, parse-platform

I am attempting to send a push notification to single user and i followed instruction found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088077/swift-parse-how-to-push-notification-to-a-specific-device-objectid)

Here is my code:

```
    let message = "Alert !!"
    let id = "QlhXkNWET6"

    let data = [ "title": "Some Title",
        "alert": message]

    let userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    userQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: id)
    let query: PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()!
    query.whereKey("currentuser", matchesQuery: userQuery)

    let push: PFPush = PFPush()
    push.setQuery(query)
    push.setData(data)
    push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock { (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if success{
            print("success")
        }
        else{
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

I debugged this code and I was able to reach the "success" statement.

However on the parse website, i get the following error:

```
PUSH ID
JXJmO93vau

TARGETING
currentUser advanced operator ($inQuery {"className"=>"_User", "where"=>{"objectId"=>"QlhXkNWET6"}}) 
SENDING TIME
January 23rd, 2016 at 8:14 PM

EXPIRATION
None

FULL TARGET
{ 
  "currentUser": { 
    "$inQuery": { 
      "className": "_User", 
      "where": { 
        "objectId": "QlhXkNWET6" 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}

FULL DATA
{ 
  "alert": "Alert !!", 
  "title": "Some Title" 
}

ERROR:
error 102: bad type for $inQuery parse.com/api/collections/collection.go:393 
inQueryVisitor.runChildQuery parse.com/api/collections/collection.go:367 
inQueryVisitor.Visit <autogenerated>:171 (*inQueryVisitor).Visit    
parse.com/api/types/query/visitor.go:27 Visit  
parse.com/api/collections/collection.go:407 (*Collection).resolveInQueries 
parse.com/api/collections/collection.go:554 (*Collection).PrepareQuery 
parse.com/api/collections/installation_collection.go:740 
(*InstallationCollection).Iterate parse.com/push/expansion/expansion_job.go:360 
(*Job).iterateOverDevices parse.com/push/expansion/expansion_job.go:296 
(*Job).perform parse.com/push/expansion/expansion_job.go:184 (*Job).Perform 
parse.com/resque/service.go:420 (*Service).perform parse.com/resque/service.go:144 
(*Service).Work.func1 /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1722 goexit
```

Any Help would greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by creating a "currentuser" column in the PFInstallation and registering the current user to it first. I drop this idea of using "ObjectId" because using email made more sense.

This is done when the user is registering for the first time.

```
let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
currentInstallation.addUniqueObject("currentuser", forKey: "channels")
currentInstallation["currentuser"] = self.emailTF.text! // adding this user email
currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
```

Now that registration of this User is done, you can send a push notification to this user by adding this to a button or anywhere else by doing the following:

```
    let pushQuery = PFInstallation.query()
    pushQuery!.whereKey("user", equalTo: "some@email.com")

    // Send push notification to query
    let push = PFPush()
    push.setQuery(pushQuery) // Set our Installation query
    push.setMessage("New Message In coming")
    push.sendPushInBackground()
```